# scipy.optimize.minimize cannot use 2D or scalar bounds

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

**Problem**

I guess `scipy.optimize.minimize` cannot use 2D bounds.

I can work around the problem by:

1. reshape input to `minimize` to 1D arrays
2. reshape the arrays back to 2D within the objective function.

But that is tedious.

Did I do something wrong? Or `minimize` really cannot use 2D bounds?

The variables should be all between 0 and 1 in my case.

Thanks.

**Doc**

The [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html#scipy.optimize.Bounds) for version 1.1.0 says bounds can be an array:

> **scipy.optimize.Bounds**
>
> ...
>
> Parameters:
>
> lb, ub : array_like, optional
>
> Lower and upper bounds on independent variables. *Each array must have 
>   the same size as x or be a scalar*, in which case a bound will be
>   the same for all the variables.
>   ...

**Versions**

- Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)
- numpy: 1.14.2 in anaconda
- scipy: 1.1.0 in anaconda

**Test**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.optimize as opt 


def obj(x):
    return x.sum()


def main():
    x = np.ones((3, 4)) 
    bounds = opt.Bounds(np.zeros(x.shape), 
                        np.ones(x.shape))
    r = opt.minimize(obj, x, bounds=bounds)
    print(r)


main()
```

**Result**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scipy_bounds.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "scipy_bounds.py", line 12, in main
    r = opt.minimize(obj, x, bounds=bounds)
  File "<...>/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 584, in minimize
    bounds = new_bounds_to_old(bounds.lb, bounds.ub, x0.shape[0])
  File "<...>/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_constraints.py", line 259, in new_bounds_to_old
    lb = [x if x > -np.inf else None for x in lb]
  File "<...>/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_constraints.py", line 259, in <listcomp>
    lb = [x if x > -np.inf else None for x in lb]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I found that `minimize` doesn't let me use scalar bounds too.

I get `'length of x0 != length of bounds'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

> x0 : ndarray, **shape (n,)**
>
> Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where ‘n’ is the number of independent variables.

So apparently yes, only 1D arrays are accepted as inputs